# POJO class should present while converting JSON to POJO?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, pojo

I am trying to to convert JSON to POJO class. This JSON I am getting from third party REST API call and I want to convert it into POJO class. For this I am using *jackson-databind* jar and below is part of my code.

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 Object modelObject; // object in which I want to convert my JSON object
 mapper.writeValue(request.getShipmentDataJson(), modelObject);
```

Here for now instead of POJO class I declared *modelObjcet* variable of **Object** type and my question is **do we need to create POJO class with required fields and getter setter methods before converting JSON to POJO?**

If yes, then **how should we create this POJO class from JSONSchema and when it get created**?

Please explain me this concept. My understanding is we POJO should get create directly from JSONSchema but when and how that I don't know. And I think once POJO get created then I can use my above code to store JSON object to POJO.

Comment: Usually you can write the POJO class(es) by hand, instead of generating them automatically from a JSON-schema. There are many good introductions available, e.g. 
[Intro to the Jackson ObjectMapper](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

You need an object with fields corresponding to incoming JSON (names and datatypes) - so jackson can populate and instantiate it.   There are tools like this:

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

to generate java code from JSON